# htaccess for seo friendly urls and php session stability

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

My problem is about php sessions. `session_id()` is not stable when I use **.htaccess** for seo friendly urls. It's always regenerated every refresh.

For example `domain.com/user/login`

But when I visit `domain.com/file.php`, `session_id()` is start to works for `domain.com/user/login`

`file.php` content;

```php
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id();
?>
```

Here is my **.htaccess** file content.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

any idea?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the path the session cookie is set for. The default is just `/` though - are you modifying this dynamically in your scripts somewhere?

Comment: no, I only use `session_start()` and `session_id()`.

Comment: I found the problem. An included file header defined session only http. I removed and solved. Thank you guys. here is removed row `header("Set-Cookie: name=value; httpOnly");`